# safe_join and content_tag approach to replace html_safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I am building a block of HTML code using Rails' `content_tag` helper. The challenge I face right now is joining HTML strings from an array with HTML elements generated by `content_tag`.

RuboCop [Rails/OutputSafety](http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_rails/#railsoutputsafety) reference.

For example:

```
options = ["<li>Three</li>", "<li>Four</li>", "<li>Five</li>"]

# This is code to generate blocks of HTML
out = []
out << content_tag(:ul,  
   content_tag(:li, "One") + 
   content_tag(:li, "Two") + 
   options.join(''),
:class => ["class_1", "class_2"])
safe_join(out)

# Expect result should be like
<ul class="class_1 class_2">
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   <li>Four</li>
   <li>Five</li>
</ul>

# Actual result
<ul class="class_1 class_2">
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   "<li>Three</li><li>Four</li><li>Five</li>"
</ul>
```

However, if I use the html_safe approach like below, it will work.

```
%{<ul>
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   #{options.join('')}
 </ul>
}.html_safe
```

Any suggestions on what I should change?

```
# New apporach
options = ["Three", "Four", "Five"]
out = []
out << content_tag(:ul,  
   content_tag(:li, "One") + 
   content_tag(:li, "Two") + 
   options.collect do |option|
      content_tag(:li, "#{option[0]}")
   end.join(""),
:class => ["class_1", "class_2"])
safe_join(out)

# New approach result
<ul class="class_1 class_2">
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   "<li>Three</li><li>Four</li><li>Five</li>"
</ul>
```

Comment: For those of you who are looking for alternative and safer ways to replace html_safe with safe_join and content_tag helpers. See the answer for the complete and descriptive solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are concatenating your output with unsafe strings coming from `options` array. This is the only place where you should use `html_safe` method for the whole output to be safe:

```
out << content_tag(:ul,  
   content_tag(:li, "One") + 
   content_tag(:li, "Two") + 
   options.join('').html_safe,
:class => ["class_1", "class_2"])
```

**Edit**

First of all `safe_join` method does not work like `html_safe` method, it doesn't only make the joined strings html_safe. It also makes html escaping if the joined string are not html_safe in order to avoid harmful content.

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/safe_join

In your case `safe_join` method didn't do anything at all with the strings in `out` array, since they had already been html_safe.

```
result = content_tag(:ul,  
           content_tag(:li, "One") + 
           content_tag(:li, "Two") + 
           options.join(''),
           :class => ["class_1", "class_2"])

result.html_safe? # => true
```

The cause of the problem is that you concatenated a safe string with unsafe one:

```
content_tag(:li, "Two") + options.join('')

content_tag(:li, "Two").html_safe? # => true
options.join('').html_safe?        # => false
```

At that moment `options.join('')` was html escaped since it wasn't safe. See the example:

```
# html tags in the second string are escaped, since it is not safe
"<li>One</li>".html_safe + "<li>Two</li>" # => "<li>One</li>&lt;li&gt;Two&lt;/li&gt;"

# nothing has been escaped, since everything is safe
"<li>One</li>".html_safe + "<li>Two</li>".html_safe # => "<li>One</li><li>Two</li>"
```

So, in order to get expected results 2 conditions must be met:

1. `safe_join` method must take array of html_safe strings. If they are not html_safe, all html tags will be escaped.
2. Do not concatenate a safe string with an unsafe one, otherwise the unsafe string will be escaped.

As you can see, you did not fulfill the second condition.

**Suggestions about the new approach**

`.join("")` method makes the result string unsafe, even if the array contains safe strings. Use `safe_join`:

```
   content_tag(:li, "One") + 
   content_tag(:li, "Two") + 
   safe_join(
     options.collect do |option|
       content_tag(:li, option)
     end
   )
```

Comment: Yes, I did the html_safe approach and it worked fine. I am trying to find an alternative way to achieve without the use of html_safe and that's why I did the safe_join approach.(reference: http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_rails/#railsoutputsafety)

Comment: I added more explanation

Comment: What you explained is really helpful. I am wondering does content_tag always generate HTML safe strings. However, if I wrap content_tag inside a [collect .. end] scope. It doesn't generate HTML safe string. Any ideas? See my new approach.  @chumakoff

Comment: Added suggestions

Comment: You are godkiller for this. Exactly what I was looking for. @chumakoff